# Should every django app within a project have it's own urls.py?

Tags: django, django-urls

I am working on a django project which will contain several apps. Each app will have their own set of models and views.

Should each app also define their own url's with a urls.py or maybe a function. What is the best practice for defining urls of apps within a django project, and integrating these urls with the main urls.py (root url conf) ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It depends. If you're dealing with a tiny website with one app, you can keep all the expressions in the same urls.py.

However, when you're dealing with a more complicated site with truly separate apps, I prefer the following structure:

- myapp

  - admin.py
  - forms.py
  - models.py
  - urls.py
  - views.py
- manage.py
- settings.py
- urls.py

Don't forget each folder needs it's own __ init__.py

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Notice the expression does not end in $, 
    # that happens at the myapp/url.py level
    (r'^myapp/', include('myproject.myapp.urls')),
)

# myapp/urls.py
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('myproject.myapp.views',
    (r'^$', 'default_view',
    (r'^something/$', 'something_view',
)
```

You also may want to look at [Class-based Generic Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/)

Comment: Updating to django 1.9, `patterns` should be replaced by a list of `url`s and you don't need 'myproject' at the beginning of the of the strings.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Confused. It seems to only handle a single app. The question was about multiple apps.

Answer (score 7):

If your app is going to display anything to the user with its own url pattern, it should probably have its own `urls.py` file. So in your base urls file, you'd have something in your urlpatterns like `url(r'', include('path.to.app.urls'))`. Then your app's `urls.py` file would have a pattern like `url(r'^$', 'path.to.app.views.view')`.

Comment: But then what about in your second app's `urls.py` file? You can only map `url(''...` once, so how does one manage multiple apps?

Answer (score 6):

If the app is mostly self-contained and having its own place in the URL hierarchy makes sense, then it should have its own urls.py. But even if it does exist, it's still only a guideline to the project developer unless [`include()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#include) is used to graft it into the project URLconf.